# Is it a problem to pass a single error to errors.Join?

Tags: go, error-handling

Go 1.20 introduces the `errors.Join` function that can wrap multiple errors. Are there any issues with calling this function and only passing in a single error?

For example, [this article](https://www.joeshaw.org/dont-defer-close-on-writable-files/) recommends against using the `defer f.Close()` idiom for writable files, because that would silently ignore any error returned by `Close`. Instead, it suggests using a named return value `err` to allow the return value of `Close` to be be propagated - unless doing so would overwrite an earlier error:

```
defer func() {
    cerr := f.Close()
    if err == nil {
        err = cerr
    }
}()
```

It seems more correct to use `errors.Join` in this scenario:

```
defer func() {
    cerr := f.Close()
    err = errors.Join(err, cerr)
}()
```

If both `err` and `cerr` are non-nil, this will now return both errors. If both are `nil`, it will return `nil`.

However, if one is `nil` and the other non-`nil`, `errors.Join` will not just return the non-`nil` error but an `errors.joinError` wrapper around it. Could wrapping an error like this cause any problems? Especially if several functions in the call stack use this approach, so a single error could end up within multiple layers of wrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `errors.JoinError` has only one non-nil error, that is still a join-error, and `errors.As` and `errors.Is` functions work as expected. This is correct no matter the level of nesting of joined errors.

The only potential problem would be if there is code like:

```
err:=someFunc()
if err==io.EOF {
  ...
}
```

then this will fail. This code has to be rewritten to use `errors.Is`.